# Call a controller when a menu is selected in single page application - angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs, single-page-application

I have created a simple Single page application with angular js. I have a index page in which the route is defined and the ng-view is called.

Index.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="SPA.Views.index" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>SPA</title>

    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="Index as ind">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openDashboard()"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openAbout()"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openContact()"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div id="main">

            <!-- angular templating -->
            <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
    <%--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="../Controllers/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.constant('routes', [
    {
        url: '/',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.aspx',
            menuItem: 'MainPage'
        }
    },
    {
        url: '/about',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'about.aspx',
            menuItem: 'aboutPage'
        }
    },
    {
        url: '/contact',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'contact.aspx',
            menuItem: 'contactPage'
        }
    }
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', '$controllerProvider', function ($routeProvider, routes, $controllerProvider) {

    //$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();

    app._controller = app.controller;

    // Provider-based controller.
    app.controller = function (name, constructor) {
        $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
        return (this);
    };

    routes.forEach(function (route) {
        $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
    });
}]);

var controllerId = 'Index';

app.controller(controllerId, function ($scope, $location) {
    var ind = this;

    $scope.openDashboard = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    }

    $scope.openOpportunity = function () {
        $location.path('/opportunity');
    }

    $scope.openContact = function () {
        $location.path('/contact');
    }
})
```

I have created three separate aspx pages for each menu and separate .js file (in which controller is defined for each page).

When the page load, it calls dashboard page by default and it throws error as

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/ng/areq?p0=dashboardController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Here, `dashboardController` is the name of the controller defined in Dashboard page.

Dashboard.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="SPA.Views.dashboard" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controllers/dashboard.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div data-ng-controller="dashboardController">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the associated controller file is as follows (dashboard.js):

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var controllerId = 'DashboardController';

    app.controller(controllerId, function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello!!";
    });
})();
```

The other pages also have the same code and that too provide the above mentioned error when a menu is selected.

When I tried to call 'dashboard.js' file in index.aspx itself, it display the page correctly.

But I don't want to call all the js file at the starting, since in future i will be using a large amount of data to display in each page and hence it might slow down the application.

Please let me know, how I should proceed to get the output by calling the controllers when that particular page is called.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear - stating `dashboardController` is not defined. You're attempting to call your controller `DashboardController` as such

```
<div data-ng-controller="dashboardController"> <!-- lowercase d -->
```

```
var controllerId = 'DashboardController'; // -- capital D
```

---

Forget the `var` and lowercase your controller name as such. Also, remove `var app = angular.module('app');`. You're overwriting your prior module definition, which you already have in `App.js`. The entire contents of `dashboard.js` should be the following

```
app.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello!!';
});
```

Comment: I have changed the typo error but still it shows the same error.. I have cleaned, built and rebuilt the solution, but still the same error..

Comment: @user3211705 remove your second app definition and give it a shot. I edited my answer

Comment: @user3211705 has `dashboard.js` loaded? Inspect the page source and navigate to it. See whats in it

Comment: oh.. My dashboard.js file is not loaded.. But I have called it in 'dashboard.aspx' page. Please let me know what I have to do to load that .js file...

Comment: @user3211705 I have no clue. That should probably be a new question. Your angular controller problem seems solved, and loading that script in your aspx page has nothing to do with angular